# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Array' is undefined error in IE 9 while using fancy box

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, fancybox

Here is my HTML code:

```
 <a id="hidden_link" href="StatusNotification.aspx" class="statusNotification fancybox.iframe"></a>
```

And this is my jquery(fancybox) code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".statusNotification").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                closeClick: false
            },
            // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox
            title: {
                type: 'float'
            }
        },
        scrolling: 'no',
        //prevents scrolling
        width: 600
    })
    $('#hidden_link').fancybox().trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

I have called the above script on page load to show a fancy box, but it doesn't show, giving the error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Array' is undefined** in IE 9
```

But it works fine in IE 7 and IE 8.

Does any one know a solution to this problem?

**EDIT:** This error occurs only if I try to trigger it using JavaScript. If I trigger it manually by clicking on the link, it works fine.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? If it's old, try updating.

Comment: i'm using jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Comment: Could you post a link to a working example or a jsFiddle?

Comment: Well the best I can suggest is to use un-minified versions of all libraries involved and see what you can see in the IE9 developer console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first add a `fancybox()` to `$('.statusNotification')` and then you add it to `$('#hidden_link')` which in this example is the same thing.

Change the javascript to:

```js
$(".statusNotification").fancybox({
  helpers   : { 
  overlay : {closeClick: false}, // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox 
  title :{ type : 'float'}
  },
  scrolling : 'no',  //prevents scrolling
  width : 600
})
$('#hidden_link').trigger('click');
​
```

This works, try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/J9uEV/